# SSLHandshakeException during the Elasticsearch lookup query

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, ssl-certificate

My TLS/SSL certificates somehow seem to have been in a mess, initially the certificate used by system was not trusted by activemq server. I resolved this issue by stopping service and creating new trust store files.
However I am not able to diagnose the SSLHandshakeException occurring during the Elasticsearch lookup query.

Exception error:
03/19/2024 06:19:37.026 ERROR Converter: Rule failed: [Find configured sources over MQ and where a queue name is defined] {trigger} = eslookup(Datasource: 'ES', Index: 'record_iap_source', NumberOfHit[...newline]
s: '100', From: '0', SortField: 'iapSourceConnectorId', SortOrder: 'ascending', FieldName: 'regex:iapSourceQueue', CriteriaValue: '.*', FieldName: 'regex:iapSourceConnectorId', CriteriaValue: {sourceC[...newline]
onnectorId}, FieldName: '$currentStep', CriteriaValue: 'ACTIVE', FieldName: 'iapSourceEnabled', CriteriaValue: 'Yes', TimeZone: 'Z', ResultFieldName: 'iapSourceConnectorId', ResultFieldName: 'iapSourc[...newline]
eQueue', Separator: ',', EscapeChar: '', MaxRetry: '0', SecondsBetweenRetries: '10') caused the message to fail: Function evaluation failed: Failing ESLookup query: ElasticsearchLookupQuery{index='re[...newline]
cord_iap_source', numberOfHits=100, from=0, sortBy=[SortOrder{order=ASCENDING, field='iapSourceConnectorId'}], lookupCriteria=[LookupCriterion{operator=REGEX, field='iapSourceQueue', criteriaValue='.*[...newline]
'}, LookupCriterion{operator=REGEX, field='iapSourceConnectorId', criteriaValue='MQ4'}, LookupCriterion{operator=EQUALS, field='$currentStep', criteriaValue='ACTIVE'}, LookupCriterion{operator=EQUALS,[...newline]
field='iapSourceEnabled', criteriaValue='Yes'}], resultFieldNames=[iapSourceConnectorId, iapSourceQueue]} after 1 attempts. Query failed with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. Message was: PKIX pa[...newline]
th building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Can someone help me resolve this issue please?

creating whole new trust store files.